# Where are the NSCocoaErrorDomain error code constants defined?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, header-files

Where are the NSCocoaErrorDomain error code constants defined? I always have trouble remembering which .h file contains the constants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many are stored in FoundationErrors.h. Others are found in AppKitErrors.h and CoreDataErrors.h

Comment: This information is also given in [the Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html).